# Let $A = C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. Show that the algebra $A/(y^{2} - x^{3})A$ is not smooth.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In the book **Smooth manifolds and Observables**, claimed:

> If $M$ is a smooth manifold, $A = C^{\infty}(M)$, $x \in M$, and $S = A \backslash \mu_{x}$, then $S^{-1}A$ is the *ring of germs of smooth functions* on $M$ at the point $x$.

The above statement it has appeared like a suggestion to solve the following problem:

> Let $A = C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. Show that the algebra $A/(y^{2} - x^{3})A$ is not smooth.

I'm not able to understand the geometrical meaning of the statement, how can I solve the problem with the given statement?

Comment: What is $\mu_x$? What is this backslash: $\backslash$? What is *this* one: $/$?

Comment: @uniquesolution $\setminus$ denotes set difference, while $/$ denotes the [quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_ring) of a ring by an ideal. I'm not sure about what $\mu_x$ stands for, though...

Comment: @antoniov.joel What does $\mu_x$ stand for? Anyway, I would interpret the hint as: "this happens if $M$ is smooth, so you can try to prove that $M$ *isn't* smooth by showing that $S^{-1}C^{\infty}(M) \neq C^{\infty}_x$ for some $x \in M$". In this case $M$ is the curve defined by $y^2 - x^3 = 0$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$, which is a classical example of curve smooth everywhere [except](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) at $(0,0)$...

Comment: @A.P. I interpreted it as $\mu \subset A$, then $\mu_{x}$ is a submanifold.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, @antoniov.joel, because $A$ is not a manifold, but a ring of functions defined on a manifold. This $\mu_x$ should be defined somewhere earlier in the text and its definition should clarify the hint. Maybe it is the set of functions that vanish at $x$?

Comment: @A.P. Sorry for that. You right. I was looking at other side.